# problem when storing image with cyclic.sh, back-end

Tags: node.js, deployment, server, backend, cyclic

this is my first deployement. I use cyclic.sh for the back-end ( node js, sql). Everything works except when i try to send an image. There is a folder 'images', in the back-end, where images are supposed to be saved. Images are also not added in my DB.

error message: Request failed with status code 500
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alv6o.png)

log (cyclic): Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'images/1676896818737IMG_3085.jpg'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUTHD.png)

I checked the front-end, images are sent to the back without any problem. When i try to display an image, already saved in the folder 'images', from the back-end "https://.........../image/88759776......jpg" it also works. The folder isn't empty and i added .gitkeep just to be sure.

I'm a beginner, usually i always manage to find solutions but here i can't.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic has a read only file system but you can use the S3 bucket included with the app to store files.

Here is the package to do it easily -
https://github.com/cyclic-software/s3fs